# transform an attribute to 0 or 1

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has an attribute called income as follows:

```
......  income
......   > 10 
......   <= 10
......   > 10
```

After the transformation, it will look like

```
    ......  income
    ......   1 
    ......   0
    ......   1
```

I want to transform this column to 1 if it's larger than 10, otherwise 0.

What I am doing currently is getting the last column from the dataframe. Then run if else statement on the last column. After that use cbind to bind first n-1 columns with the last column. I want to know other more efficient solutions.

I just learn how to use R. I really appreciate if you could provide more details for your solutions.

Comment: `ifelse(income >10, 1, 0)`, What have you tried?

Comment: `ifelse(income == "> 10", 1, 0)`, if it's a factor or character (and if the string is always "> 10", without variation is spaces, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In R, the integer values of `TRUE` and `FALSE` are `1` and `0`, respectively.  Since you want `1` for "yes it's '> 10'" and `0` for "no it's not", we can simply convert the result of a logical comparison to their corresponding integer values.

```
df$income <- as.integer(df$income == "> 10")
```

where `df` is your data.

Comment: `+(df$income == "> 10")` will save characters

Comment: True, but I don't do it like that. :)